# Как обьединить массив и массив массивов по ключу?

Tags: c#, json, linq

У меня есть следующий список:

```
var result = (from cab in cabinets
                     join mod in modemsCount on cab.OrganizationID equals mod.OrganizationID into modCount
                     from modcount in modCount.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join objectc in objectCount on cab.OrganizationID equals objectc.OrganizationID into objectcCount
                     from objectccount in objectcCount.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join modActive in modemsActiveCount on cab.OrganizationID equals modActive.OrganizationID into modActiveCount
                     from modActivecount in modActiveCount.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join device in deviceCount on cab.OrganizationID equals device.OrganizationID into devCount
                     from devcount in devCount.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join deviceActive in deviceActiveCount on cab.OrganizationID equals deviceActive.OrganizationID into devActiveCount
                     from devActivecount in devActiveCount.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join regul in regulCount on cab.OrganizationID equals regul.OrganizationID into RegulCount
                     from Regulcount in RegulCount.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join regulActive in regulActiveCount on cab.OrganizationID equals regulActive.OrganizationID into RegulactiveCount
                     from RegulActivecount in RegulactiveCount.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join TVC in TVCount on cab.OrganizationID equals TVC.OrganizationID into TVCCount
                     from TVCcount in TVCCount.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join TVAC in TVActiveCount on cab.OrganizationID equals TVAC.OrganizationID into TVACCount
                     from TVACcount in TVACCount.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join ContourC in ContourCount on cab.OrganizationID equals ContourC.OrganizationID into CONTOURCount
                     from CONTOURcount in CONTOURCount.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join ContourActiveC in ContourActiveCount on cab.OrganizationID equals ContourActiveC.OrganizationID into CONTOURActiveCount
                     from CONTOURActivecount in CONTOURActiveCount.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join userC in userCount on cab.OrganizationID equals userC.OrganizationID into userCCount
                     from userCcount in userCCount.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join userAC in userActiveCount on cab.OrganizationID equals userAC.OrganizationID into userACCount
                     from userACcount in userACCount.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join userWeb in userwebcabCount on cab.OrganizationID equals userWeb.OrganizationID into userWebCount
                     from userWebcount in userWebCount.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new 
                     {
                         OrganizationID = cab.OrganizationID,
                         CabinetName = cab.CabinetName,
                         CabinetURL = cab.CabinetURL,
                         ModemCount = modcount?.NumberOfRecords ?? 0,
                         ObjectCount = objectccount?.NumberOfRecords ?? 0,
                         ModemActiveCount = modActivecount?.NumberOfRecords ?? 0,
                         DeviceCount = devcount?.NumberOfRecords ?? 0,
                         DeviceActiveCount = devActivecount?.NumberOfRecords ?? 0,
                         RegulatorCount = Regulcount?.NumberOfRecords ?? 0,
                         RegulatorActiveCount = RegulActivecount?.NumberOfRecords ?? 0,
                         TVCount = TVCcount?.NumberOfRecords ?? 0,
                         TVActiveCount = TVACcount?.NumberOfRecords ?? 0,
                         ContourCount = CONTOURcount?.NumberOfRecords ?? 0,
                         ContourActiveCount = CONTOURActivecount?.NumberOfRecords ?? 0,
                         UserCount = userCcount?.NumberOfRecords ?? 0,
                         UserActiveCount = userACcount?.NumberOfRecords ?? 0,
                         UserMobileCount = userWebcount?.NumberOfRecords ?? 0
                     }).ToList();
```

И есть второй список, но он уже - массив с массивами.

[image: Массив 2]

```
var urls = result.Select(a => a.CabinetURL).Distinct().ToList();
        List<JObject> jsonDataList = new List<JObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            
            string jsonData = org.GetDataHttp(urls[i], 1, 250); // Получение сделок компании по ссылке
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData)) { Console.WriteLine($@"{i}, continue"); continue; } // Если такой ссылки нету в амосрм - continue

            JObject z = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
            z["_embedded"]["url"] = urls[i]; // Добавление искомой ссылки в результат для дальнейшего джойна
            Console.WriteLine($@"Data finded at index {i}");
            jsonDataList.Add(z);
        }

        List<ICollection> leadData_List = new List<ICollection>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataList.Count; i++)
        {
            var lead = jsonDataList[i];
            var url = lead["_embedded"]["url"];
            var leadData = lead["_embedded"]["leads"].Select(a => new
            {
                id = (int)a["id"],
                name = (string)a["name"],
                url = url
            }).ToList().ToList();
        }
```

Мне нужно объединить эти две коллекции по ключу URL.
Пробовал циклом, выцепляя списки по одному, и выводя в переменную, и просто по индексу - не получилось. Может что не так сделал.
Есть какие то способы решить данную проблему?

Comment: А почему вы JSON парсите как `JObject`, а не десериализируете в структуру классов? ИМХО, сейчас у вас костыли, с кучей лишнего и странного. Да и вообще, когда у вас куча повторяющихся строк в коде, это первый признак того, что вы делаете что-то не то.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, вы на основе первой коллекции запрашиваете элементы для второй коллекции. Какой объект вы хотите прикрепить к ссылке?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то должно быть что-то вроде этого:
Всего вашего контекста нет, пишу почти наугад.

```
    var urls = result.Select(a => new { url = a.CabinetURL, obj = a }).ToList();
    List<JObject> jsonDataList = new List<JObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        
        string jsonData = org.GetDataHttp(urls[i].url, 1, 250); // Получение сделок компании по ссылке
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData)) { Console.WriteLine($@"{i}, continue"); continue; } // Если такой ссылки нету в амосрм - continue

        JObject z = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
        z["_embedded"]["url"] = urls[i].url; // Добавление искомой ссылки в результат для дальнейшего джойна
        Console.WriteLine($@"Data finded at index {i}");
        jsonDataList.Add(z);
    }

    List<ICollection> leadData_List = new List<ICollection>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataList.Count; i++)
    {
        var lead = jsonDataList[i];
        var url = lead["_embedded"]["url"];
        var leadData = lead["_embedded"]["leads"].Select(a => new
        {
            id = (int)a["id"],
            name = (string)a["name"],
            url = url,
            obj = result.Where(w => w.CabinetURL == url).Select(s => s.obj).ToList()
        }).ToList();
    }
```

obj - исходный объект из первого списка.